# If inside button does not work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, if-statement

```
var menu_open:Boolean = true;

MenuContainer1.MenuContainer2.logo.nav_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onNav2);

function onNav2(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if (menu_open) {
        trace (menu_open);
        MenuContainer1.gotoAndPlay(1);
        menu_open = false;
        trace ("open");
        trace (menu_open);
    } else {
        trace (menu_open);
        MenuContainer1.gotoAndPlay(2);
        menu_open = true;
        trace ("close");
        trace (menu_open);
    }
}
stop();
```

why this does not work it does not trace else when i click, but if before i compile i swap     "var menu_open:Boolean = true;" to     "var menu_open:Boolean = false;" it does trace else!

Comment: did you really read your code before posting it here?
you set menu_open to true initially, so on click you'll step into the if(menu_open) part, no?

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `menu_open` to `true` at the top of your code, so the first time you enter `onNav2()` your `if` statement will run the first part (this assumes you don't change `menu_open` anywhere else in your code).  In there you set `menu_open` to `false`, so the *second* time it's called it should run the `else` portion of your code.  Then the next time it should run the `if` portion, as `menu_open` has been set back to `true`.